# Easier way to assign instyle CSS

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have a color picker assigning colors to a button using the setStyle command.  I then have to parse the value of the color because it is in hex.  I assign that color manually to the object. I have two problems that I can think of. Sometimes my parsing is incorrect and it will not assign the color.  The second problem is because I am setting the style with a fixed string. I am looking to add more inline style later on with the color picker. My first way of thinking was to assign each hard coded inline css as a string and concat them at the end to one big SetStyle call.  I was wondering if there is a better option such as modifying the external css?

```
private void displayproperties()
{
    AnchorPane PropertiesPane = Main.getGeneralPaneProperties();
    PropertiesPane.getChildren().clear();
    //backgroundColor
    Text bgcolor = new Text();
    bgcolor.setText("Background Color");
    bgcolor.setLayoutX(0.0);
    bgcolor.setLayoutY(10.0);
    PropertiesPane.getChildren().add(bgcolor);
    System.out.println(getStyle());
    final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
    colorPicker.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
            {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color:"+ colorPicker.getValue().toString().substring(2));

                }

            });
    PropertiesPane.getChildren().add(colorPicker);
    String bordercolor = "-fx-border-color:  #545454";
    colorPicker.relocate(bgcolor.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX()+5,bgcolor.getBoundsInParent().getMinY());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix the parsing: Don't use `toString()`: there's no guarantee the format of the returned `String` will be the same in future releases. This means your code could potentially break if your user upgrades their JVM installation.

There doesn't seem to be a nice way to do this: you just need to grab the red, green, and blue values from the color and build the appropriate string. One way would be something like this:

```
public String getCssSpec(Color c) {
    int r = (int) (c.getRed() * 256) ;
    int g = (int) (c.getGreen() * 256) ;
    int b = (int) (c.getBlue() * 256) ;
    return String.format("rgb(%d, %d, %d)", r, g, b);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
```

Then just do

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
  setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + getCssSpec(colorPicker.getValue()));
}
```

For the problem of needing to apply multiple styles, the best way is probably to concatenate all styles into a string, and call setStyle(...). I think the way I would do this is to define a class with properties for each of the styles you want to set:

```
class ButtonStyle {
  Color backgroundColor ;
  Color borderColor ;
  // etc
}
```

and then define a method to build the whole css string from the various properties. That way you can update a property and regenerate the inline style with a method call or two.